# Martingale convergence theorem for the Bernoulli distribution

Tags: martingales, stochastic-analysis

> Consider a sequence $(X_n)_{n\ge1}$ of i.i.d random variables with
>   distribution $\mathcal{B}_{1/2}$, and set
>
> $$S_n := X_1 + \cdots + X_n$$
>
> Fix $p \in (0,1),\,q=1-p,$ and define
>
> $$M_n := (2p)^{S_n}(2q)^{n-S_n}$$
>
> $(M_n)_{n\ge1}$ is a martingale w.r.t the filtration generated by
>   $(X_n)_{n\ge1}$. Using the appropriate martingale convergence theorem,
>   show that $(M_n)_{n\ge1}$ admits a.s. limit $M$.

I've already shown that admits a.s limit $M$, but I can't determine it.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

The limit is $1$ if $p=q$. This is trivial.

If $p \ne q$, then using $S_n/n \to 1/2$ almost surely (Law of Large number), we have $M_n \to 0$ almost surely.

To see, consider any fixed sequence $s_n$ such that $s_n/n \to 1/2$. It's not difficult to see that 
$$
(2p)^{s_n} (2(1-p))^{n-s_n} \to 0
$$
unless $p=1/2$.

Comment: I do not follow this argument. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Math1000 See update

Comment: Here we have $S_n$ and not $S_n/n$ though.

Comment: @Math1000 We don't need $S_n$ to converge. Just replace $S_n$ by $(1+o(1))n/2$. This is enough to make the sequence converge to $0$.